# Xamarin image locations in the folder

Tags: xamarin

I was trying to reverse engineer a Xamarin project and write native Android program. Not being familiar with Xamarin and not wanting to open up the Visual Studio IDE :-) where do I look for all the images of the project. I was trying to find the icon and the splash screens in the sln folder but couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Android projects, images are usually located in the Resources folder.

Comment: I did notice that Xamarin created a bunch of folders for each OS implementation [or not sure if the developer did] but the assets folder was empty -  .\ReverseEnggProject\ReverseEnggProject.Droid\Assets. I found some icons in ..Droid\Resources\drawable.

Comment: yeah, I should have told you Resources.  Non-image assets go in Assets

Comment: Thanks Jason. It looks like all the images were there in the resources folder. I just need to check the right folders since it creates a separate set of folders for each OS implementation.

Comment: Oh wow, I don't have a good enough reputation ;-) to mark the answer as correct.